# Symfony2 data fixtures

Tags: symfony

very new to Symfony2 so trying to working things out.  Got a couple of tables.  First one is called availability_alert.  This table has the usual stuff like an id, but the important thing to note is that it does not have a link to anything.

The second table is call booking_class.  This one has a couple of fields, one of which is availability_alert_id.  This value is linked to the id field in my first table.

I had a working application, but decided to move it to Symfony.  I used my existing database to produce some entity classes.  In my BookingClass Entity, I have a link to the AvailabilityAlert id.

```
/**
 * @var \AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="availability_alert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $availabilityAlert;
```

Now for some reason, it set the setter to this field like so

```
public function setAvailabilityAlert(\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert $availabilityAlert = null)
{
    $this->availabilityAlert = $availabilityAlert;

    return $this;
}
```

So I first want to make sure this is correct?

Next, I am doing some Data Fixtures, so I do
`$alert = new AvailabilityAlert();`

And then set a few other bits and pieces.  I then do one for the other table
`$bookingClass = new BookingClass();`

However, when I try to set the id
`$bookingClass->setAvailabilityAlert($this.$alert->getId());`

It tells me it is expecting an AvailabilityAlert but instead it is getting a String.

So I was just wondering what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736945/symfony-2-fixtures-for-many-to-many-relationship/27738460#27738460) question. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to add a string instead of an AvailabilityAlert object to your BookingClass object.

Instead of this:
`$bookingClass->setAvailabilityAlert($this.$alert->getId());`

Simply try this:
`$bookingClass->setAvailabilityAlert($alert);`